# how to change nth byte of text file in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to add a number for each megabyte of a text file.

For example, for a 24MB text file, I want to change the 1048576th (1024*1024) byte to 1, 2097152th (2mb to bytes) byte to 2, and so on. For the 10mb mark (10485760th byte), I'd like to add a 1 at 10485759th byte & a 0 at the 10485760th byte.

What I thought of was to use the `awk` command I found [online](https://www.unix.com/emergency-unix-and-linux-support/194687-replace-nth-position-character-all-lines-file.html), something like this:

```
awk '$0=substr($0,1,1048575)"[some number here]"substr($0,1048577,length($0))' input.txt > output.txt
```

But for this command it doesn't seem to be possible to change the input in `[some number here]`, is there a way I can move a pointer (or something similar) for a certain number of bytes, change the byte pointed by the pointer, then move the pointer again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `ksh93` shell using its `>#((...))` seeking operator, you could do:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -

LC_ALL=C
block=${1?Please specify a block size}; shift

for file do
  for (( n = 1; n * block <= size; n++ )); do
    printf %s "$n" >#(( n * block - ${#n} )) || break
  done 1<> "$file" >#(( size = EOF ))
done
```

(to be used as `that-script 1048576 file1 file2...`).

Same with `zsh` and its `sysseek` builtin:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system || exit
block=${1?Please specify a block size}; shift

for file do
  {
    sysseek -u 1 -w end 0 || continue
    (( size = systell(1) ))
    for (( n = 1; n * block <= size; n++ )); do
      sysseek -u 1 $(( n * block - $#n )) &&
        printf %s $n ||
        break
    done
  } 1<> $file
done
```

`bash` has no seeking operator nor any operator to get the size of the file though you could always call interpreters that do (like `ksh93`/`zsh`/`perl`) within a `bash` script if you really had to use that shell.

Comment: Was wondering: couldn't one do the same in `sh` and `bash` with `{ dd bs="$block" skip="$n" count=0 && printf %s "$n"; } <>"$file" 1>&0` ?

Comment: @LL3, not all `dd` implementations do the `seek()`ing with `count=0`. You'd need to skip back `${#n}` bytes as well. Using `perl` as I suggested there would make it more reliable/portable.